# Measuring average transfer rate for data through Node.js socket

Tags: sockets, node.js, data-transfer

I have a regular TCP socket connection between a Node.js application (using standard [net.Socket](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)), and some other application.

Suppose I send a 1MB buffer:

```
socket.write(new Buffer(1048576));
```

While this is done in a non-blocking manner, obviously the data is not transmitted instantaneously.

**How can I measure the data rate that the underlying system is sending the internal stream buffer, from my Node.js application?**

Ultimately I just need to know the average speed of data being sent to the client on the other end over the last several seconds.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use [callback in write](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback)

```
var net = require('net');
var s = net.createConnection(8888);
s.on('connect', function() {
    function test() {
       var len = 512*1048576;
       var start = +new Date();
       var b = new Buffer(len);
       b.fill('x');
       s.write(b, function() {
           console.log(len + ' bytes written, ' + (1000*len/(+new Date() - start)).toString() + ' bytes/sec');
           test();
       });
    }
    test();
});
```

with `nc -l 8888 > /dev/null` on the other end I get around 350M bytes/sec

Comment: Not a bad idea!  Thanks!  I'll have to do a bit of juggling, since in reality, `.write()` is called many times in my application.  Subsequent writes may occur while previous writes are still in progress, which will throw off timing.  But, I think I figure something out.